# Django doesn't log the user in

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a login function, however when I try to login with a user that is not admin Django's authenticate function returns None even though the user exists in the database and the function receives the right username and password.

```
def login_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        print(username, password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            return render(request, "orders/login.html", 
            {"message":"Username and password did not match."})
    else:
        return render(request, "orders/login.html")
```

login template:

```
{% extends "orders/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Login
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

  <div class="forms">
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        {% if message %}
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">{{ message }}</small>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn button" id="button1" >Log In</button>
      <a class="btn button" href="{% url 'register' %}" role="button" id="button2">Register</a>
    </form>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

url.py :

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("menu/<product>/", views.menu, name="menu"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("add_to_cart", views.addToCart, name="add_to_cart"),
    path("cart", views.cart, name="cart"),
    path("confirm", views.confirm, name="confirm"),
    path("login", views.login_user, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_user, name="logout")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def login_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        print(username, password)
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                If user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                return redirect("/")
            else:
                return render(request, "orders/login.html", 
                    {"message":"User does not exist."})
        else:
            return render(request, "orders/login.html", 
            {"message":"Username and password did not match."})
    else:
        return render(request, "orders/login.html")
```

Comment: Please post the login form template and your url and check if there any error on your server log

Comment: The url to the website? its ran on my computer. There seem to be no errors.

Comment: greate, show your urls.py and when you click on the login button you will have a traceback on the django server log could you please add it also

Comment: posted urls.py, can you please point me to where I can find the server log? thanks

Comment: Here //   path("login/", views.login_user, name="login")       // you need to add a slash after login

Comment: Still the authentication returns none even though the correct username and password are received by the login_user function

Comment: print(username, password) did that print something on the console?

Comment: when you log in what happen on your browser ?

Comment: It prints the message "username and password did not match", since even though the print statement returns the correct username and password, the authenticate function returns None

Comment: Add If user.is_active as i did in the updated answer

Comment: It never gets to that line since you put it after "if user is not None" but the user is None

Comment: I figured out the problem, there was a problem with the user registration form. Thank you for your help.